# Mostrar Nombre Java Jframe

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo una consulta. Tengo el siguiente código java y quiero que el botón saludar me capture el nombre que digite el usuario y cuando le de en el botón saludar me lo muestre en el Jframe.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Ventanita extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public Ventanita() {
    jPanel.add(label);
    jPanel.add(jTextField);
    jPanel.add(jButton);
    jPanel.add(label1);
    jPanel.add(label2);
    add(jPanel);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame x = new Ventanita();
    x.setSize(400, 400);
    x.setVisible(true);        
    x.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

JLabel label = new JLabel("Nombre");
JTextField jTextField = new JTextField("10");
JButton jButton = new JButton("Saluda");

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Hola");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" ");
JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

}

}
```

Comment: Pero el ejemplo es funcional, al menos se muestra el formulario??

Comment: Si claro muestra el formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con base al ejemplo que diste, ya tu editas las posiciones de los objetos, te recomiendo que repases.

```
package pruebasdemetodos;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author HANSELC2
 */
public class Ventanita extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Nombre");
    JTextField jTextField = new JTextField("10");
    JButton jButton = new JButton("Saluda");

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Hola");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Cambio");
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
public Ventanita() {
    jButton.addActionListener(this);
    jPanel.add(label);
    jPanel.add(jTextField);
    jPanel.add(jButton);
    jPanel.add(label1);
    jPanel.add(label2);
    add(jPanel);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame x = new Ventanita();
    x.setSize(400, 400);
    x.setVisible(true);        
    x.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    label2.setVisible(true);
    label2.setText(jTextField.getText());
}


}
```